# how to write mathematical equations and symbols in IBM Conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog, watson-iot

I have created a chat bot using Conversation Service of IBM Watson but I am not able to write mathematical equations and symbols in the intents, entities and dialog. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematical symbols such as +,-,* or / are just characters and can be used in intent/entities examples. So you could create an intent `#add` with `+`, `plus`, `add` as an examples. 
Then you can use predefined `@sys-number` entity to detect numbers (just turn it on in entities, system entities tab). You would then create a dialog node with a condition `#add && @sys-number.length == 2` - to be sure there are two numbers in the user input - and in the Watson says, you could write expression such as:

`<? @sys-number[0].numeric_value + @sys-number[1].numeric_value ?>`

to get the result.

Comment: Thanks :) this was helpful.